# Setting superscript on JSON data.I am using Retrofit 1.9 and Gson for serialization as well as the field are Observable using Data Binding

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

This is my JSON Data :

```
{
    "Main": {
        "country": "USA",
        "State": California,
        "City": San Jose
    },
    "transport": [{
        "id": 711,
        "Train": "yes",
        "Bus": "yes",
        "CarPool": "Yes"
    }],
}
```

This is my Model class :

```
public class MainPoint {

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public String getTrain() {
        return train;
    }
}
```

I am getting data in this way in another class :

```
public class MyData {

    MainPoint mPoint;

    public String getCountry {

        if (mPoint.getCountry() != null) {
            return mPoint.getCountry();
        }
    }
```

I want to add code here for setting superscript on `getcountry` value as 1 when `getTrain` response is Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Superscript is formatting, you're going to have to take care of that in the presentation layer, not the data layer.

Comment: :I do not get what do you mean by it.